# Systemd and Puma in an infinite startup loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, systemd, puma

I'm banging my head against the wall with puma and systemd. I used foreman to set up my systemd files, but can't get puma out of its restart loop. Ubuntu 16.

```
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 systemd[1]: Stopped rajlogviewer-web.service.
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 systemd[1]: Started rajlogviewer-web.service.
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: APP_DIR = /home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer, SHARED_DIR /home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer/shared
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] Puma starting in cluster mode...
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Environment: production
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Process workers: 2
Jun 19 02:48:12 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Preloading application
Jun 19 02:48:14 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Jun 19 02:48:14 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Listening on unix:///home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
Jun 19 02:48:14 ip-172-31-28-225 rajlogviewer-web.service[8954]: [8954] * Daemonizing...
Jun 19 02:48:24 ip-172-31-28-225 systemd[1]: rajlogviewer-web.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 19 02:48:24 ip-172-31-28-225 systemd[1]: Stopped rajlogviewer-web.service.
Jun 19 02:48:24 ip-172-31-28-225 systemd[1]: Started rajlogviewer-web.service.
```

It just keeps restarting indefinitely. Here is my systemd init file
/etc/systemd/system/rajlogviewer-web.service

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer/current
#Environment=PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rajlogsViewer/bin:$PATH
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer/current/
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rajlogsViewer/bin:$PATH exec /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.3.3 do bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rajlogviewer
/shared/config/puma.rb --daemon'
Restart=no
RestartSec=10
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

The app usually boots in 5 seconds when booting with 'cap production puma:start' which works, so RestartSec=10 ought to work. Making it 20 seconds makes no difference.

Nothing interesting in the puma.stderr.log and puma.stdout.log .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `--daemon` option from the systemd, there are several types of unit:

> Configures the unit process startup type that affects the
>   functionality of ExecStart and related options. One of:
>
> **simple** – *The
>   default value.* The process started with ExecStart is the main process
>   of the service.
>
> **forking** – The process started with ExecStart spawns a
>   child process that becomes the main process of the service. The parent
>   process exits when the startup is complete.
>
> **oneshot** – This type is
>   similar to simple, but the process exits before starting consequent
>   units. dbus – This type is similar to simple, but consequent units are
>   started only after the main process gains a D-Bus name.
>
> **notify** – This
>   type is similar to simple, but consequent units are started only after
>   a notification message is sent via the sd_notify() function.
>
> **idle** –
>   similar to simple, the actual execution of the service binary is
>   delayed until all jobs are finished, which avoids mixing the status
>   output with shell output of services.

The default value is **simple**, for the sake of puma configuration you use `--daemon` options which contradict with the systemd configuration.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it. sometimes one thinks he is smart, but this has proven otherwise!!!